# Count how often a value occurs Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to identify how often the word "old" is used in a column in Excel. This is an example of the cells in the column:

- UK old account
- Dollars old
- This is now old don't use
- Pounds
- China account
- Old

The formular I am working with is:

```
=COUNTIF(A3:A21778,"old")
```

However, this is only returning the number of cells in that column having only the word "old", which is 1. I need a formula that will return the value 4 (the number of cells that contain "old")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ensure that only `old` is found when it is it's own word, where we do not get false positive with `cold` or `oldies`, we need to switch to SUMPRODUCT and bracket the search word and the searched area with spaces:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" " & "old" & " "," " & A3:A21778 & " "))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `=COUNTIF(A3:A21778,"*old*")`

Comment: FWIW: This will also count `oldies` or `cold`. it is not word specific.  It will find anywhere the letters are in that combination..  That may be okay in this instance but just pointing it out.